# CakePHP login without use of password, ONLY username

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

After reading the post: [logging without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531410/how-to-cakephp-logging-in-without-password)

I made a personal attempt:

AppController:

```
function beforeFilter(){
$this->Auth->loginError = "This message shows up when the wrong credentials are 
 used";       
 //$this->Auth->authError = "This error shows up with the user tries to access a part
 of the website that is protected."; 
    //$this->Auth->authError = "";
    $this->Auth->fields = array(
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' =>   null 
   );
```

UsersController, inside `add()`:

```
// Save new user
   if ($this->User->save(array('username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'],
          'password' => $this->Auth->password(null),
          'name' => $this->request->data['User']['name'],
          'surname' => $this->request->data['User']['surname'],
          'chosenLayout' => $this->request->data['User']['chosenLayout'],
          'dateCreated' => $this->request->data['User']['dateCreated'],
          'dateModified' => $this->request->data['User']['dateModified'],
          'role_id' =>$this->request->data['User']['role_id']        
   ))) {

    $this->Session->setFlash(__('message_success_user_added', 
    array($this->request->data['User']['username'])), 'default', array(), 'success');
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   } 
   else {
    // Validation error
 $this->Session->setFlash(__('message_fail_validation'), 'default', array(), 'fail');
   }
```

Then entered as admin and created some dummy users with null or random password.
Checking the database encrypted passwords were all the same ( a hashed null string) which means the modification in `add()` function worked...

Inside UsersController `login()`:

```
// Login User
public function login() {

    // Check if the user is already logged in
    if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User.id')){ 

        // Redirect to login page
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginRedirect); 
    }
    else{
        // If the user is not logged in

        session_set_cookie_params(0); 

        // If the request is a POST request
        if ($this->request->is('post')) { 
            //get credentials
            $this->username = $this->request->data['User']['username'];
            $this->password = $this->request->data['User']['password'];
            $this->domain = $this->request->data['User']['domain'];
            //debug($this->username);
            debug($this->domain) ;
            //Check if username exists in local DB 
            //debug($this->User->findByUsername( $this->username ));
            if ($this->Auth->login(
                          array(
                           'username'=> $this->username,
                            'password'=> null)

                         )){

                //   debug($this->Auth->login(array(
                  //          'username'=> $this->username,
                    //        'password'=> null
                        // )));

    // Successful login
    // Get all the user information and store in Session
    //debug($this->Auth);
$this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    debug($this->User->id);
    debug($this->User);
$this->User->contain(array('User', 'Role' => array('Ui', 'Action.name')));
    $this->Session->write('User', $this->User->read());

        $actions = array();
foreach ($this->Session->read('User.Role.Action') as $key => $value){
array_push($actions, $value['name']);
}
$this->Session->write('User.Role.Action', $actions);
debug($actions);

// Render different layout depending on user type

   if($this->Session->read('User.Role.Ui.name') == Configure::read('usertype.msp')){

   $this->Session->write('SessionValues.ui', Configure::read('usertype.msp'));
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'PortStats', 'action' => 
   'index');
    }
else if($this->Session->read('User.Role.Ui.name') == 
    Configure::read('usertype.tsc')){

    $this->Session->write('SessionValues.ui', Configure::read('usertype.tsc'));
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'PortStats', 'action' => 
    'index');
                        }
else if($this->Session->read('User.Role.Ui.name') == 
    Configure::read('usertype.superAdminUserType')){
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'Uis', 'action' => 'index');
                        }

                    // Redirect to main login page
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginRedirect);

                    }
                    else {
                    // Failed login user
                    session_destroy();
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Login failed: 
          access not granted'), 'default', array(), 'fail');

                    }

                }
    }
}
```

Then I try to login with my new users.I get the failed login message.
Which means `$this->Auth->login` returns `false`.

It must be as easy as that but something is going wrong.

In the meantime my debug trace:

> Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>   [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 85]

Comment: $this->Auth->fields = array(
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' =>   null 
   ); is wrong.  Which field you want to check in place of password? Like in the link you mentioned, they are authenticating with nickname and shoesize. $Auth->fields = array(
    'username' => 'nickname',
    'password' => 'shoesize'
); So whatever field you want to check, you can set it e.g. you want to authenticate with field say code, you can write 'password' => 'code'

Comment: You are confusing a few things here. What you are doing is not a login as it normally is. Thus you cannot just use the internal auth methods as you intend to. Why all this overhead if you just set the session manually using login($data)? You could probably removed 3/4 of your lines here.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify it. It is not a login, but a registration process, so don't confuse those two totally different things.

You just

- create the user including proper validation
- on success use Auth->login($user['User']) to set the auth session manually
- only then redirect manually to where you want the user to go after a registration here

For a live example see https://github.com/dereuromark/cakefest/blob/master/Controller/AccountController.php#L166

Comment: Actually my register method is called add() and it is used to save a new instance of User model using post data via a form.
So I dont think I get what you mean...
Your code is clean and thorough thx! But still I need to login ONLY by using username field password independent.

Comment: Login by username only is equivalent to login in with any "unique" field of the User record, thus equivalent to a simple manual session overwrite via `login($data)`. This is still not what a normal login is. You still seem to mix those two different ways of writing the session auth. One is actual login (identification via user credentials), the other ALWAYS logs in and does not check for anything.